# How can I access a value which is defined in a __init__ function, as a parameter to my test_case

Tags: python

I have my test case data, which is created in **init** function. I need to use it as a parameter for my test case, but unable to access test_case_data

```
class something(object):

    def __init__(self, logger):
      #do something
      self.test_case_data = ... #Got test case data

    @pytest.mark.p0  
    @pytest.parameterize("paramter1, parameter2, .. , ..", test_case_data)

    def test_something():
       #do_something
```

This is what my code looks like. I want to use test_case_data as a parameter, which is defined in a **init** function.

Comment: class something(object):
        def __init__(object):
              #do something
             self.test_case_data = ... #Got test case data
      
          @pytest.mark.p0
          @pytest.parameterize("paramter1, parameter2, .. , ..", test_case_data)
          def test_something():
                #do_something

Comment: Is `test_something` meant to be inside or outside of your class?

Comment: it is inside the class. Got some indentation fault.

Comment: Could you show us pytest decorator?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/ @MishaVacic

Answer (score 1):

**init** isn't run until you make an instance of the class. To access:

```
class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "value"

instance = ClassName()
print(instance.variable)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but the thing to remember is that those data members declared in **init** don't exist until you make an instance of the class.